# Vue.js - Takes too long to 'destroy' components

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZjN3.png)I have a time-table component that is created with vue.js and it includes around 200 child timeline components as nested form (I wanted to upload image but couldn't without 10 reputations).

The problem now is that it takes more than 6 seconds to destroy this component.

Chrome says that 'remove' function (,which is called by vue.js everytime we destroy a component,)  is called many times, and each of them takes around 20 - 40ms.

The vue.js remove function is like below:

```
function remove (arr, item) {
  if (arr.length) {
    var index = arr.indexOf(item);
    if (index > -1) {
      return arr.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

and it seems that the first argument ,arr, is either a few VueComponents or more than 2000 Watcher objects.

Now, my questions are:
1. What is 'Watcher' in this context and why the number it exceeds 2000?
2. Why it takes such long time despite I do not handle like 10000 components or so?

I guess it is the matter of specification of vue.js, but please help me if you have a similar problem or have any idea about this matter. Thank you!

[image]
Above is how the timeline component appears, and each of gray-background panels and purple background panel(with a man icon) are child components.
When you click a purple panel, vue-router makes routing to the page of the detail, and at that time all of components are destroyed (that is when the problems above occurs)

Comment: Your deletion time is normal for Vue (see benchmark https://vogloblinsky.github.io/web-components-benchmark/). The issue here might be that removal is done by removing item by item, instead of a subarray of items. You might want to show us more of your code, i.e. how you call function `remove`, what is `watcher` that you are talking about. Your current code sample is not enough to figure out anything.

Comment: Do you have destroy/beforeDestroy hooks in your timeline child components? I think the code of the timeline component can be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry for being late,
I guess showing codes to explain is a little complex to me because of many types of child components are included in the parent component.
Instead, I added a screen capture and the description of how the component works. I can show you my code if you could tell me which part of the image is required. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here, on the same remove function. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AurelienMaigret, this question is technically unanswerable as it does not have sufficient info to reproduce and/or debug the problem. If you need an answer to a similar one, I suggest you write up your own question which could allow others to reproduce and debug the issue. Ideally it should contain a [mcve].

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with some very small components, it takes 30 seconds+ to unmount/remove some 100 components. I thought it was because of a beforeDestroy hook but even with it removed it still takes too long, interface is lagging.

Answer (score 19):

We have experienced similar issues and found that all share the same underlying problem: too many components that depend on the same reactive object. These are the 3 main cases that may impact any project:

- Many `router-link` components
- Many components (any kind) when Vue I18n is installed
- Many components that directly access the Vuex store on its render or computed properties.

Our approach is to avoid accessing shared reactive objects on the render and computed properties functions. Instead, pass them as `props` (reactive) or access them on the `created` or `updated` hooks (not reactive) to store in the component's `$data`. Read below for more details and each of the 3 cases.

### A brief explanation of Vue 2 reactivity

*(skip this if you don't need it)*

The Vue reactivity basically relays on two intertwined objects: [Watcher](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.12/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js#L4418) and [Dep](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.12/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js#L701). Watchers have a list of dependencies (Deps) in the `deps` attribute, and Deps have a list of dependants (Watchers) in the `subs` attribute.

For every reactive thing, Vue instantiates a Dep that tracks reads and writes on it.

Vue instantiates a Watcher for every component (actually, for the `render` function) and every Computed Property. The Watchers *watch* a function during its execution. While *watching*, if a reactive object is read, the associated Dep notices the Watcher, and they become related: The `Watcher.deps` contains the `Dep`, and the `Dep.subs` contains the `Watcher`.

Afterwards, if the reactive thing changes, the associated `Dep` [notifies](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.12/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js#L720) all its dependants (`Dep.subs`) and tells them to update (`Watcher.update`).

When a component is destroyed, all its Watchers are destroyed as well. This process implies iterating each `Watcher.deps` to remove the Watcher itself from the `Dep.subs` (see [Watcher.teardown](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.6.12/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js#L4601)).

### The problem

All the components that depend on the same reactive thing insert a Watcher on the same `Dep.subs`. In the following example, the same `Dep.subs` contains 10,000 watchers:

- 1,000 items rendered (e.g. a grid, an infinite scroll, ...)
- Each item implies 10 components: itself, 2 router-link, 3 buttons, 4 other (nested and not nested, from your code or third party).
- All components depend on the same reactive object.

When destroying the page, the 10,000 watchers will remove themselves from the `Dep.subs` array (one by one). The cost of removing themselves is `10k * O(10k - i)` where `i` is the number of watchers already removed.

In general, the cost of removing `n` items is `O((n^2)/2)`.

### Workarounds

In case you render many components, avoid **accessing** shared reactive dependencies on the `render` or computed properties.

Instead, pass them as `props` or access them on the `created` or `updated` hooks and store them on the component's `$data`. Bear in mind that the hooks aren't *watched* so the component won't be updated if the source of data changes, which is still suitable for many cases (any case where the data won't change once the component is mounted).

If your page renders a long list of items, the [vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller) is bound to help. In this case, you can still access shared reactive dependencies because the vue-virtual-scroller reuses a small pool of your components (it does not render what is not seen).

Take into account that having thousands of component might be easier than you expect because we tend to write small components and compose them (actually a good practice)

**Case: Vuex**

If you do something like this in your render o computed property, your component depends on all the chain of reactive things: `state`, `account`, `profile`.

```js
function myComputedProperty() {
    this.$store.state.account.profile.name;
}
```

In this example, if your account does not change once the component is mounted, you can read it from the `created` or `beforeMount` hook and store the `name` on the Vue `$data`. As this is not part of the render function nor part of a computed property, there is no Watcher *watching* the access to the store.

```js
function beforeMount() {
    this.$data.userName = this.$store.state.account.profile.name;
}
```

**Case: router-link**

See the [issue #3500](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3500)

**Case: Vue I18n**

This has the same underlying problem but with a bit different explanation. See the [issue #926](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/926)

Comment: Awesome description, it helps a lot for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not a vue problem, see on your mixins/options.
Eg. `i18n` (my pain) in every of 200 components will show the same result. It removes a lot of watchers on `beforeDestroy`. Without `i18n` the list works 30 times faster.
How to fix it? Move the slow hook-handlers to the parent component and get needed data/methods from it.

The sample with `i18n`

```
Vue.mixin({
    beforeCreate() {
        if (this.$options.useParentLocalization) {
            this._i18n = parent.$i18n;
        }
    },
});
```

Usage:

```
new Vue({
  // i18n, <-- before
  useParentLocalization: true,
  components: {
    Component1
  }
})
```